# Как обновлять виджеты в Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Добрый день.

Что-то ни в документации, ни в гугле не могу найти ответ на мой вопрос.

Как изменить виджет уже после того, как приложение запущено?

Например, у меня есть Label. Я могу изменить его свойство text, и если я это делаю до выполнения app.run(), то это изменение применится.

Но после запуска приложения у меня уже не получается как-то манипулировать интерфейсом.

Например, у меня приложение задано таким классом:

```
class Main(App):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = Label(text='', color=(1, 1, 1, 1))

    def build(self):
        return self.root

    def msg(self, text=''):
        self.root.text = text
```

Если запустить метод msg до app.run(), то на экране я вижу строку, которую передал в качестве аргумента msg:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Main()
    app.msg('test')
    app.run()
    # вижу на экране "test"
```

Но если запускаю msg после app.run(), то на экране ничего не меняется.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Main()
    app.run()
    app.msg('test')
    # Экран пустой :(
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не правильно понимаете логику Kivy. После app.run() не имеет смысла что делать вообще, так как ваше приложение уже в цикле. Любые свойства виджета в Kivy меняются без применения какой-либо функции обновления, на лету. Создайте кнопку и привяжите событие на функцию msg.

Больше информации здесь - https://habrahabr.ru/users/HeaTTheatR/topics/