# Как изменить значение текста Label в kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Как создать Label ( желательно через python, а не через kv ) так, чтобы его значение потом можно были изменить. И как его потом изменить из другой части программы?

Comment: Т.е. как виджеты обновлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, который иллюстрирует "изменить из другой части программы":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label


def change_text(label, period, new_text):
    old_text, label.text = label.text, new_text
    Clock.schedule_once(lambda _: change_text(label, period, old_text), period)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        label = Label(text='A')
        change_text(label, period=1, new_text='B')
        return label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Это слегка изменённый пример из [вводного руководства](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html), который каждую секунду изменяет текст с A на B и обратно.

Текст изменяется присваиванием `label.text` нового значения. Следующее изменение назначается, используя [`Clock.schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html).

Для сравнения, вот пример, где в одном месте и определение Label и обработчик событий:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import cycle
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label()

        def change_text(_, choices=cycle('AB')):
            label.text = next(choices)
        change_text(None)
        Clock.schedule_interval(change_text, 1)
        return label



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас бы ещё понять, как обращаться к Label не по имени, а по id, но это уже вопрос отдельного вопроса, уж простите за тавтологию.

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев: если хотите по id обращаться, можно по id. Задайте отдельный вопрос, не забыв привести минимальный пример кода (.kv файл, где id определён и .py файл, в котором вы хотите этот id использовать. [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

```
label = Label(text="Text")
label.text = "New text"
```

Вот связанный вопрос - [Как обновлять виджеты в Kivy?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683751/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-kivy/683802#683802)