# Как обратиться к Label по id созданным динамически в Питон коде (не Kv)

Tags: python, kivy

Как обратиться к Label`ам, зная только их id и месторасположение? Как вообще обращаться к элементу, если он находится в другой директории от расположения "обращающейся" команды?

Я разобрался, как назначать id элементу, но как к нему обращаться из вне? Пусть у меня есть следующая программа :

```
n =  4   # где 4 - кол-во cols и rows, предполагается использование 

         # n=int(input())
p=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]  # Это список изначальных значений, которые должны отображаться на Labels

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return scr

def change():              #Пример какого-то изменения p
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            p[i][j]+=1

scr = Screen()      #В такой последовательности вложены Labels
box = BoxLayout()
BOX = BoxLayout()
grid = GridLayout(cols=n)
scr.add_widget(box)
box.add_widget(BOX)
BOX.add_widget(grid)
for i in range(n):     # Цикл создания Labels и присваивания из значений
    for j in range(n):
        label = Label(text=str(p[i][j]))
        label.id = 'id:'+str(i) + ':' + str(j)
        grid.add_widget(label)
if __name__=='__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Как в этом конкретном примере максимально простым способом сделать так, чтобы при изменении значения p в функции change() менялось и значение текста у соответствующего label`а?

Comment: Причём имеется ввиду обращение по id из кода python в первую очередь.

Comment: опишите конкретную задачу (в текущей постановке `id` не будут работать и они не нужны), но каким решением заменить, зависит уже от специфики задачи (слишком много вариантов иначе подходящий для разных случаев).

Comment: Изменил исходный запрос.

Comment: не используйте сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи. Словами (в вопросе) опишите, какое намерение у кода (если забыть как он реализован, то какое поведение вы ожидаете?)

Comment: Это не то, чтобы сломанный код. Он просто недоделанный. Я, собственно, и спрашиваю, как его доделать. Т.е. вышеописанное работает, запускается, но не делает то, что мне нужно - т.к. я тупо не реализовал это, т.к. не знаю, как так сделать. А нужно мне тут, чтобы в ф-ии change при изменении p[i][j] менялся связанный с ним текст Label`а

Comment: Ещё раз: «если забыть как это реализовано, то какое поведение вы ожидаете?» (с точки зрения человека, который на экран, запущенного приложения смотрит и тыкает мышкой)

Comment: Я ожидаю, что, изменяя значения p ( а делать этот человек это будет с помощью кнопочки, которая выполняет ф-ю change()), будет меняться и значение labels на экране.

Answer (score -1):

`id` определяются в Kv языке. В Питон коде не имеет смысла их пытаться определять — это не обновляет `root.ids` словарь (`root = ContainerWidget()`), который позволяет обращаться к элементам по их id, определённым в соответствующем Kv правиле: `root.ids.some_id`.

Как динамически набор Label обновлять зависит уже от специфики задачи. Существует множество вариантов, подходящих для разных случаев. Простым вариантом является [передача только что созданного объекта Label в обработчик событий (closure)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706278/23044).

> Я ожидаю, что, изменяя значения p ( а делать этот человек это будет с помощью кнопочки, которая выполняет ф-ю change()), будет меняться и значение labels на экране.

Чтобы по нажатию на кнопочку, обновить набор Label, удобно представить его с помощью [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html), который связывает данные и отображаемые виджеты. Чтобы быстро найти RecycleView в дереве виджетов, можно в Kv указать `id: container`:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
<ContainerWidget>
    container: container
    Button:
        text: 'Update data'
        on_release: root.update_data()
    RecycleView:
        id: container  # used as root.container in the Python code below
        viewclass: 'Label'
        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 4
```

В корневом виджете лежат кнопка и RecycleView, куда кнопки будут добавляться.

По нажатию на кнопку вызывается `root.update_data()` метод:

```
class ContainerWidget(BoxLayout):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update_data(self):
        for i, d in enumerate(self.container.data):
            d['text'] = str(int(d['text']) + 1)  # compute a new value
            self.container.data[i] = d  # update
```

В данном случае, когда RecycleView прямо в самом корне лежит и определять `container` свойство необязательно, но в общем случае RecycleView можно как угодно глубоко в ContainerWidget передвинуть без изменения кода. RecycleView всегда как `self.container` доступен в ContainerWidget классе в Питон коде, где бы он ни лежал. RecycleView можно и в Kv и в Питон-коде определить, не меняя код, который обращается к нему через `self.container` (в отличии от `self.ids.container`).

В целом, [рекомендуется (best practice)](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code) явно свойства определять, используя ObjectProperty как c `self.container` выше, вместо обращения к `self.ids.container`.

`root.container.data` содержит данные Label, которые создаются в приложении динамически:

```
class ContainerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ContainerWidget()
        # generate random integer from the range including ends
        n = random.randint(1, 24)
        root.container.data = [{'text': str(i)} for i in range(n)]
        return root
```

Генерируется случайное число в указанном диапазоне чисел включая края. В данном случае `viewclass: Label` поэтому словари внутри списка содержат `text`.

Присваивание `self.container.data[i] = d` в `update_data()` обновляет значение для соответствующей Label.

Полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""#:kivy 1.10.0
<ContainerWidget>
    container: container
    Button:
        text: 'Update data'
        on_release: root.update_data()
    RecycleView:
        id: container  # used as root.container in the Python code below
        viewclass: 'Label'
        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 4
""")


class ContainerWidget(BoxLayout):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update_data(self):
        for i, d in enumerate(self.container.data):
            d['text'] = str(int(d['text']) + 1)  # compute a new value
            self.container.data[i] = d  # update


class ContainerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ContainerWidget()
        # generate random integer from the range including ends
        n = random.randint(1, 24)
        root.container.data = [{'text': str(i)} for i in range(n)]
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ContainerApp().run()
```

Comment: Не ясно чем вызван минус. Как можно улучшить этот ответ? Буду признателен любому комментарию.

Answer (score -2):

Очень просто. У каждого корневого виджета имеется свойство ids, которое возвращает список объектов (дочерних элементов), к которым можно обращаться по их id:

```
obj_label = root_widget.ids.уникальный_id
```

Теперь работайте с obj_label как с обычным объектом Label.

Да, если вы хотите таким образом дергать id из Python кода, то, как мне правильно подсказывают, ничего не выйдет. Сначала нужно получить список объектов через root_widget.children, а уже потом смотреть какие id какого объекта вам нужны.

Comment: автор в Питоне `id` задаёт — они не попадут `root_widget.ids`.

Comment: labels у автора глубоко вложены. В `root_widget.children` вы увидите BoxLayout объект, а не Label.

Comment: То есть, ты считаешь, что у BoxLayout нет свойства children? Я описал принцип, а ты начинаешь путать человека! Зачем ты это делаешь?