# Как реализовать цикл в kv в kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Необходимо в языке kv реализовать такой цикл, который бы создавал заранее неизвестное число объектов и присваивал им id. Я вроде понял, как это сделать в самом коде python, но там с id взаимодействовать не получается, с другой стороны, не могу создать цикл в языке kv. Аналог в python выглядел бы примерно так:

```
for i in range(n):
    Lab = Label(text = str(app.p[1])
    Lab.id = 'id:' + str(i)
```

Здесь p это какой-то список со значениями

Comment: Вместо попытки циклы в kv тащить, просто не используйте id и пишите циклы в Питоне, [как я вам уже писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706541/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-label-%d0%bf%d0%be-id-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-kv#comment1053384_706541)

Comment: Как в таком случае обращаться по id? Смотрите,что я пытаюсь сделать : у меня есть некий список p, который будет меняться. А также у меня есть n-ое количество кнопок, где n изначально неизвестен. Мне нужно в процессе написания кода создать эти кнопки, а также уметь потом значения текста на этих кнопках ( здесь кнопки- Labels ) изменять. Если я буду использовать циклы питона, как мне обратиться по ID к labels? Ибо через kv я умею обращаться. В другом случае, если обращаюсь по id через kv, как мне реализовать цикл? Вы советуете не мучиться и реализовать цикл через питон, как тогда менять знач.?

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в ваш исходный вопрос как я попросил. Как я сказал есть множество решений, но какое предпочесть зависит от конкретной задачи: к примеру я уже приводил решение где вы вновь созданные Label как аргументы в closure сохраняете. Или просто контейнер в удобном месте разместите (к примеру BoxLayout) и добавляйте Label к нему динамически. Потом чтобы до этих Label добраться, по прямым потомкам пройдите этого контейнера. См. [пример container](https://goo.gl/CNcezR) (обратите внимание что *глубоковложенный* container доступен как свойство *корневого* виджета)

Answer (score 1):

А если, например, так:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


ID_BY_LABEL = dict()

class MyWidget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1
        self.spacing = 10
        self.padding = 10

        label_list = ['Собака', 'Сосед', 'Кот', 'Биткоин']
        for i, title in enumerate(label_list):
            label = Label(text=title)
            label.id = 'id:' + str(i)

            ID_BY_LABEL[label.id] = label

            self.add_widget(label)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: А есть ли возможность непосредственно в kv воссоздать цикл?

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев, хз, но точно вы можете сами создать скриптом kv и заполнить его тем, что захотите, хоть 100 Label, kv ведь простой текстовый формат :)

Comment: Дак в том то и прикол. Мне нужно создать заранее неизвестное ( меняющееся от запуска к запуску ) число Labels, значение которых я мог бы изменять. Чтобы менять значение, можно обращаться по id, но это, вроде как, по крайней мере у меня, получается только через kv. Чтобы создать цикл, нужно пользоваться самим python`ом, вот и получается замкнутый круг.

Comment: Окей, как в твоём случае обратиться к этому лэйблу по id из другой части программы?

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев, по-моему, у вас какая-то дичь с ТЗ :) Я слабо представляю что вы там с ними делаете, зачем делаете и т.п. :) Если вам так нужно иметь эти id, то имеет смысл их хранить в том месте, откуда они будут доступны всем. Я в ответ добавлю глобальный словарь `ID_BY_LABEL` с id. Словарь запомнит их, а как к нему вы будете обращаться уже другой вопрос

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев, кст, если количество label заранее неизвестно, то как вы такое собирались в kv добавить? Значит откуда-то значение приходит об их количестве. В общем, какие-то мутные условия :)

Comment: Я несколько переформулировал задачу, может кто-то даст ответ?  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706541/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-label-%D0%BF%D0%BE-id-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-kv

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев, предложенный мной ответ не может быть ответом на вопрос?

Comment: как в вашем случае реализовать изменение значений текста на Label`ах?

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев, обратиться к ссылкам label'ов через словарь ID_BY_LABEL и менять значение

Comment: Как я понял, тут фишка в том, что значения словаря ссылаются как-бы в то же место, куда и label, в один и тот же объект. За счёт этого оно и работает. Действительно крайне просто, спасибо большое. К слово, оно( надпись ) будет изменяться динамически? Уже после запуска приложения?

Comment: @ЕгорЗверев, боюсь я не знаю ответа на этот вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя реализовать циклы в KV. И если такие мысли вообще возникают, то вы не правильно понимаете философию Kivy.

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях к первому ответу автор писал про создание цикла в .kv файле. Можно сделать так:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class A(GridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return A()

Elips().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
<A>:
    cols:1
    on_parent:
        for i in range(n): self.add_widget(Button(id=str(i)))
```

Но не уверен насколько это правильно использовать.