# Как назначить действие ToggleButton?

Tags: python, button, kivy, toggle

Создаю внутри GridLayout через цикл несколько кнопок, и под каждой строкой кнопок элемент Label.
Как назначить действия кнопкам чтоб по нажатию одна из них меняла текст Label?
Назначать метод `on_press` и присваивать id/group элементам я умею, но вот как внутри это описать

[image: Расстановка элементов для ясности]

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можно так:

```
class MyApp(App):

    def upgrade_lab(self, *args):
        self.lab.text = 'bbbb'

    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(cols=3)

        for i in range(3):
            self.tog_b = ToggleButton(text=str(i))
            self.tog_b.bind(on_press=self.upgrade_lab)
            grid.add_widget(self.tog_b)

        self.lab = Label(text='aaaa')
        grid.add_widget(self.lab)

        return grid

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Это было бы слишком просто, я же создаю элементы через цикл, то есть тех же одноименных self.lab и self.tog_b будет много и нужно чтоб каждая строка кнопок меняла именно Label под ними, по id как-то

Comment: Ну или мне хотя бы вывести принтом id кнопки, на которую я нажал

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706952/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2-kv-%d0%b2-kivy/1127660#1127660 посмотрите первый ответ, представленный способ может подойти вам.